# How to call Queue push function asynchronously in lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have integrated the AWS SQS queue service to store each request. I have added `Queue::push()` function in to the middleware, which causing delay in request.
Because it is calling synchronously, It is wait till data get pushed to the Queue. 
I wanted to do achieve it asynchronously.

Comment: Improved a bit the title question, added code sample to `Queue::push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async) package which offers a lot of great ways to initiate an async call by using tasks, processes, etc.

Comment: Can we achieve it with thread? If yes how come it possible? I have tried to extend the Thread but it returns me fatal error Thread not found.